# How to use jq to extract a particular field from a terraform plan to show resources that are updated or changed?

Tags: json, terraform, jq

I just want to be able to have a small quick view or list of what is changing with a terraform plan instead of the long output given by a terraform plan.

So far I think it can be done with a terraform plan and jq.

Here is what I have so far -

I run a plan like this:

```
terraform plan -out=tfplan -no-color -detailed-exitcode
```

Then I am trying to use jq to get the changes or updates using this:

```
terraform show -json tfplan | jq '.resource_changes[] 
                            | select( .change.actions 
                                     | contains("create") or contains("update") )'
```

It gives me the error :

> ```
> jq: error (at <stdin>:1): array (["no-op"]) and string ("create") 
> cannot have their containment checked
> ```

My jq skills are not the best - can anyone update my jq to work or is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: `contains(["create"])` should work.

Comment: It'll be good if you could provide a minimal reproducable example, eg what is the shape of the output of `terraform plan -out=tfplan`

I suspect that the terraform command is creating unexpected output that is causing jq to complain.

Eg, I found something about terraform creating no-op values in their output here - https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/explanation-of-no-op-value-in-action-field-of-terraform-json-out-file/31149

Comment: I think this could work `terraform show -json tfplan | jq '.resource_changes[] | select( .change.actions[] | contains("create") or contains("update"))'`.

Answer (score 1):

`contains` checks if one array is a subarray of the other, recursively (substrings are matched too; note the "d" in "create" vs "created"):

```
$ jq -n '["created"] | contains(["create"])'
true
```

You can use the SQL-style `IN` filter:

```
$ jq -n '"create" | IN("created", "foo")'
false
$ jq -n '"created" | IN("created", "bar")'
true
```

So for your concrete use case you would probably want something like the following:

```
terraform show -json tfplan | jq '
  .resource_changes[]
  | select(
    .change.actions as $actions
    | "create" | IN($actions[])
    or "update" | IN($actions[]))'
```

Or using `any/2`:

```
terraform show -json tfplan | jq '
  .resource_changes[]
  | select(any(.change.actions[]; .=="create" or .=="update"))'
```